# Local Path? How to find that

Tags: php

Having a problem with a script I downloaded.

the codes says to enter the local path..

I'm not really sure how to figure out the local path. I'm not using a server on my computer so I don't if the local path would look like the example in the code.

```
<?
$localpath = "/home/xxxxxx/public_html/ddps"; //Local Path Where You Installed The Script

$sitepath = "http://www.halogamertags.com/ddps"; //WWW Path To Script
```

I get this as the error in the browser.

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/xxxxxx/public_html/ddps/downloads/Andrew Ferrara.docx) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/halogam1/public_html/ddps/doupload.php on line 7

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpExSwrS' to '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/ddps/downloads/Andrew Ferrara.docx' in /home/halogam1/public_html/ddps/doupload.php on line 7
```

Comment: That's correct.  Local path will always be a file path.  If you used a URL, it wouldn't be considered "local" even if it was a URL to your current system.

Comment: echo "This is the directory of this file: ".__DIR__;

Comment: @Dagon and @Endophage I added the next line in the script which contains the information I inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$localpath = "/home/halogam1/public_html/ddps/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Local path is to where the script is located. Normally can be seen as:

```
 ddps (relative call to folder)
```

Same as:

```
 /home/domain/public_html/ddps
```

on both local and web servers. Other wise it will look something like:

```
 c:\users\me\ddps (On Windows)
      OR
 MAC_OS:Desktop:ddps (On Mac)
```